# Text next to a link image

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I know how to put a text next to an image by applying float:left to the img tag, but when I give it a link e.g `href="#"` the text won't stand stick to the image, it falls down. To give more info about the project, my `<a>` tags in the `<p>` tags are display: inline-block; and the css I applied to the img tags is:

```
float:left;
margin-right: 15px;
border:0px;
```

So why is this happening? I want my image to stand just as it does when I don't put it between `<a>` tags.

Comment: Why do you have `<a>` as `display: inline-block`? Removing that and allowing them to flow normally may solve your issue.

Comment: @Adrian because if I don't apply it, what comes after links falls down a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float: left;` means the element is floated to the left of the content within the same parent. Since you are wrapping the image inside of an `<a></a>` tag, the image is being floated to the left of the content within the `<a>`.

If you apply the float to the `a` instead of the `img`, then the `a` will be floated to the left of the content in *its* parent, as desired.

Comment: +1 Problem and solution example in jsbin link [link](http://jsbin.com/evozof/3/edit)